# how to use getElementById to get the table specified with id

Tags: javascript, html

i want to use js to add one row in an exsiting table,however i got an error:document.getElementById() is null,here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>use js to create one row</title>
</head>
<body >

<tr id="table">
    <td>row 1</td>
</tr>

<script>
    window.onload = function(){  
        var td = document.createElement("td");
        td.innerHTML = "add row";
        var tr = document.getElementById("table");
        tr.appendChild(rows); 
    }   
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `rows` is undefined in your code, and `tr` is invalid outside of a `table`.

Comment: first learn table structure and basic javascript and do some research and then ask a question at here.

you could search on google for table structure : 
table structure in html
and you could ask google : how to add a row in a table using javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `tr` is invalid outside of a table, the browser is basically ignoring the `tr` element entirely and just putting the text `row 1` directly in `body`, which is why `getElementById` didn't return an element; it was never created by the browser when parsing the HTML.

Put the `tr` in a `table` (and ideally in a `tbody`):

```
<table>
  <tbody id="tbody">
    <tr>
      <td>row 1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

and append to the `tbody`, being sure to create a row (`tr`) as well as a `td` since your apparent goal is to add a row:

```
var td = document.createElement("td");
td.innerHTML = "add row";
var tr = document.createElement("tr");
tr.appendChild(td);
document.getElementById("tbody").appendChild(tr);
```

It's also almost never useful to use the `load` event on `window`, since it doesn't get run until **very** late in the page-load process (waiting for all other resources, including all images, to load); that delay means the user can easily start interacting with your page before your code has run. Instead, use [modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules) (which are run as soon as the DOM is in place, but not before) or just put your script at the very end of the HTML, just before the closing `</body>` tag.

Live example:

```html
<table>
  <tbody id="tbody">
    <tr>
      <td>row 1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<script>
  (function() {
    var td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = "add row";
    var tr = document.createElement("tr");
    tr.appendChild(td);
    document.getElementById("tbody").appendChild(tr); 
  })();
</script>
```